# How to Turn Off/On a WARN directive for the whole Delphi Project ?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi we have multiple warn the compiler the provide to protect you do do something bad. Some are errors other warns etc.
I want to turn off the Warn for SYMBOL_DEPRECATED for all my files in the project.
But I just found ways to do it by file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Project->Options->Hints and Warnings** from the menu.

Change **Deprecated Symbol** in the list to `False`. You'll need to do it for each target (Debug Win32, Release Win32, etc.), as they're maintained separately.

(Not sure why you'd want to do that, BTW. Deprecated symbol warnings are meaningful, as opposed to the **Platform Unit** when you're clearly doing a VCL Windows app and not FMX. You should heed deprecated symbol warnings, as those mean that code can break in the future and you're not prepared.)